# Создание главного меню в unity

Tags: unity3d

Помогите подсказать общую реализацию, как сделать главное меню. Игру я хочу сделать на телефон. В главном меню будет виден список всех уровней. Получается, при клике на иконку уровня будет открываться данный по счету уровень. Я не знаю, как точно сделать. Сделать так, чтобы определенный скрипт на камере проверял нажатие на все уровни(Это очень много условий if) и запускалась определенная сцена или можно сделать как-нибудь иначе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

1. Создаем такой скрипт:

   ```
   class SceneLoad : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public int sceneIndex;

       public void OnBtnClick()
       {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Cоздаем префаб кнопки загрузки уровня (GameObject с компонентом Button и нашим скриптом)
3. В префабе, для события клика в компоненте Button добавляем ссылку на метод `OnBtnClick` класса `SceneLoad`, написанного ранее в пункте 1.
4. Кидаем префаб на сцену и выставляем нужный номер сцены в поле `sceneIndex` в написанном скрипте `SceneLoad`. И так для каждого уровня. (Для удобства можно кидать их в какой либо Layout)

Все. Теперь при клике на кнопку, будет загружаться указанный на кнопке уровень.

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

1. Создаем скрипт:

   using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

   public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {

   public void SceneFunc() 
   { 
   SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1); 
   }

   }
2. Создаём UI кнопку и к ней привязываем скрипт. Добавляем функцию, созданную в скрипте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ему нужен список всех уровней, значит все кнопки должны отвечать за разные уровни. А у Вас кнопка будет загружать только следующий.

Comment: @ANUCHEEKIBREEKI Для перехода на необходимую сцену достаточно поменять прибавляемое число в скрипте для соответствующей кнопки.

Comment: и для каждой кнопки писать свой скрипт? Даже если кнопок будет 100 штук? Тогда уж лучше добавить переменную и менять ее для каждой кнопки, но это уже будет решение, предложенное мной.